# WTS32api : WTSEnumerateSessions returns Error Code 5

Tags: c#, winapi

I am using `WTSEnumerateSessions` to get user sessions. Most of the cases it works fine, but sometimes it returns 0 user session.

So we added `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` to get to the reason behind this. and we got error code 5 - which says access denied.

```
IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
Int32 pCount = 0;
Int32 retval = WTSEnumerateSessions(server, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref pCount);
Log.Write(pCount.ToString());
Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

Int64 current = (int)ppSessionInfo;

if (retval == 0 || pCount == 0)
{
    Log(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) I got to know it is Access Denied, but I wanted to know more. why it got access denied while performing such lower leveled API and that too some times not always

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw): *"To enumerate a session, you must enable the query information permission."* and *"To enumerate sessions running on a virtual machine hosted on a RD Virtualization Host server, you must be a member of the Administrators group on the RD Virtualization Host server."* Are you meeting those prerequisites?

Comment: @IInspectable I need to check for the first point. I will get back to you tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Also, the error check is wrong. It needs to be `if (retval == 0)`. `GetLastWin32Error()` will not return a meaningful value for any other condition. Adding the P/Invoke declaration is a good idea, too.